# Count the cells which are not visited in matrix in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have N x M matrix where N is number of rows and M is number of columns.
I have to perform t tasks.
Each task contains row,column_1,column_2. It means that the cell between column_1 to column_2(inclusive) of given row are now visited.

Ex:

task 1: 2,3,6 means that cells 3 to 6 are now visited cell in row 2.

Suppose, I have 4 x 4 matrix and I have 3 tasks.

task 1 : 3,2,3

task 2 : 2,1,3

task 3 : 3 1,3

So, now number of cells which are not visited are 10. (tasks can include cell number which are previously visited).

[image: Explanation]

I have to count the cells which are not visited.
Since N and M can be between 1 and 10^9, I am unable to solve the problem.
I have solved the problem when N and M are smaller in java but couldn't solve for larger input.(Tasks will not be more than 1000)

I am not asking for code but can anyone just give me optimize approach to solve this problem ?

Edit 1:
input will be like(for given example):

4 4 3

3 2 3

2 1 3

3 1 3

First line indicates N M t respectively. Hence N=4, M=4 and t=3.
Next t lines will show row column_1 column_2 respectively.

Comment: You havent shown how is the task input is provided. share that for further details on how to make it distinct list.

Comment: Hint: For each row, try merging the intervals if overlapping otherwise just decrease the number of elements in the interval from (n*m). This operation can be performed in linear time if the intervals are arranged properly.

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt I have added input format now.

Comment: @Shubham It is not necessary that intervals will be arranged properly. Suppose in 20 x 20 matrix, task 1: 1 2 3, task 2: 1 2 7 task 3: 1 15 18 task 4: 1 12 14. How to solve these types of test cases?

Comment: @YashMehta You'll have to arrange the intervals before trying to merge them.

Comment: Could you post an [MVCE] for the solution you have for a small matrix ? It will help me understand the need.

Comment: @YashMehta: Are the indices given for a task 0-based or 1-based??

Comment: @YashMehta Plz have a look at my answer, it breaks down your requirement i guess

Comment: @User_Targaryen indices given for task is 0 based.

Comment: If the problem is from a contest site, it would be good to add a link to the post.

Comment: @Gassa Hackerrank World Codesprint 7 problem.

Comment: Hmm. Please refer to the [rules](https://www.hackerrank.com/worldcodesprint#rules). This is an ongoing contest. Code copying would be outright cheating by point 3, so you are right not to ask for it. I'd say asking for algorithmic help is also forbidden by point 2, but I'll leave that to others' judgement.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have to have some way of storing information about visited cell, so why not do the counting at the time of cell visit? Without seeing some code sample form You I can propose 2 approaches for counting visited cells. 
Then, as others have pointed out, once you have the visited cell count, getting the not visited count should be straightforward.

In both the Matrix is formed from 3 classes:

- Matrix managing class - here you create your matrix and get its metadata
- Matrix row class - here you store your cells and implement "visit" logic
- Matrix cell class - your business class

First approach will calculate total visited cell count at the time you ask for it with complexity O(n) where n is the number of rows in your matrix, while the second approach will increment the visited number at each new visit and getting the visited count will have complexity of O(1).

I would go with the second approach, but again I do not know what will suit your needs.

**First**

A Row Class contains a list with one cell for each column in your matrix, and a Cell class has a boolean property that indicates if that cell has been visited before. This property is set when a cell has been visited.
Now you can count the number of cells that have been visited in a row.

Example MatrixManager class used for matrix manipulation:

```
public class MyMatrixManager {    
    private ArrayList<MyRow> matrixRows;

    public void createMatrix(){
        // matrix creation logic
    }

    public void visitCells(int rowIndex, int startColumnIndex, int endColumnIndex){
        MyRow row = matrixRows.get(rowIndex);
        row.visitCells(startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex);
    }

    public int getVisitedCellCount(){
        int visitedCellCount = 0;
        for (MyRow matrixRow : matrixRows) {
            visitedCellCount += matrixRow.getVisitedCellCount();
        }
        return visitedCellCount;
    }
}
```

Class that represents a row in the matrix. This will count each time a cell has been visited for the first time:

```
public class MyRow {
    private int visitedCellCount;
    private ArrayList<IMyCell> cells;

    public MyRow(ArrayList<IMyCell> cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
        this.visitedCellCount = 0;
    }

    public void visitCells(int startIndex, int endIndex){
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            IMyCell cell = cells.get(i);
            if(!cell.isCellVisited()){
                visitedCellCount++; // Count cell visit
            }
            cell.visit();
        }
    }

    public int getVisitedCellCount(){
        return visitedCellCount;
    }   
}
```

Example interfece for the Cell class. visit method is your business logic method. The implementation of this interface should set the isCellVisisted property:

```
public interface IMyCell {
    public boolean isCellVisited();
    public void visit();
}
```

Not sure if performance of iterating through 10^9 row object will be ok for you, so:

**Second**

Have one counter for all your cells. Have the Matrix managing class log each cell visit using the observer pattern:

Example of the manager Class, note that it implements a ICellVisitListener:

```
    public class MyMatrixManager implements ICellVisitListener{

    private ArrayList<MyRow> matrixRows;
    private int visitedCellCount;

    public void createMatrix(ArrayList<MyRow> rows){
        // matrix creation logic, Object init..

        // subscribe to events
        for (MyRow row : rows) {
            row.addCellVisitListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void visitCells(int rowIndex, int startColumnIndex, int endColumnIndex){
        MyRow row = matrixRows.get(rowIndex);
        row.visitCells(startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex);
    }

    public int getVisitedCellCount(){
        return visitedCellCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void cellVisitedForFirstTime() {
        visitedCellCount++;
    }    
}
```

Listener interface (note that you can change this so it will give you the visited cell object):

```
public interface ICellVisitListener {
    void cellVisitedForFirstTime();
}
```

The Row class will now raise an event for each first time a cell has been visited:

```
public class MyRow {
    private List<ICellVisitListener> cellVisitListeners;
    private ArrayList<IMyCell> cells;

    public MyRow2(ArrayList<IMyCell> cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public void addCellVisitListener(ICellVisitListener listener){
        cellVisitListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeCellVisitListener(ICellVisitListener listener){
        cellVisitListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void visitCells(int startIndex, int endIndex){
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            IMyCell cell = cells.get(i);
            if(!cell.isCellVisited()){
                onCellFirstVisit(); // raise event so the visit count is incremented
            }
            cell.visit();
        }
    }

    public void onCellFirstVisit(){
        for (ICellVisitListener listener : cellVisitListeners) {
            listener.cellVisitedForFirstTime();
        }
    }   
}
```

And the IMyCell inteface again:

```
public interface IMyCell {
    public boolean isCellVisited();
    public void visit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of a solution (no code as required).

First, note that we can solve the task for each row separately.
Moreover, only the rows with at least one actual input matter, others are completely not visited.
So, the first step will be to store the information regarding each row together.
I'd use a map from row-number to the list of inputs which belong to that row.
First, read the entire input into such map.
Then, iterate over the map and solve the task for each individual affected row.

Next, we have a simpler version in one row.
There are some segments on a line, and we want to know the total length of their union.
This can be solved in the following way.
Instead of storing segments themselves, create two *events* for each segment: segment start at say coordinate *x<sub>1</sub>* and segment end at coordinate *x<sub>2</sub>*.
Now, sort all events by their *x*-coordinate, and iterate over them in sorted order, maintaining the count of segments currently opened but not closed.
For an open event, the count changes by +1, and for a close event, it changes by -1.
Between two consecutive events at coordinates *x<sub>prev</sub>* and *x<sub>next</sub>*, if the count is non-zero, add *x<sub>next</sub> - x<sub>prev</sub>* to the answer.
Otherwise, add nothing.
In the end, the answer is the total length of the union of the segments in the row.

The complexity in each row with *k* is *O(k log(k))* because of sorting events.
The total complexity is therefore *O(t log(t))* where *t* is the number of inputs, since the sum of all *k* is *t*, and the worst case is when all inputs affect the same row.
The coordinates don't affect the complexity.
However, be sure to choose appropriate data types: for example, the answer for N = M = 10<sup>9</sup> can be of order 10<sup>18</sup>, so we have to perform calculations in a `long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to count number of cells that the tasks visit. While counting you need to ignore repeated cell visit. Once you have number of unique count of visited cell. you can calculate not visisted cell easily.

```
int notVisitedCell=(row*col)-totalUniqueVisistedCellsByTasks;
```

The approach to count unique cell from tasks, there are many approach. To help you further you need to show how the java input is provided in your program.

Edit 1:
As per the comments this is my changed solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Maverick
 */
public class MatrixCalculcation {

    public List<String> taskList;
    public HashMap<String,Integer> hm;
    public int row;
    public int column;

    public void notVisited()
    {
        hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        String[] tmpArr;
        int tmpLen=0;
        String tmpStr;
        for(String task:taskList)
        {
            tmpArr=task.split(" ");
            tmpLen=tmpArr.length;

            int lower=Integer.parseInt(tmpArr[1]);
            int upper=Integer.parseInt(tmpArr[2]);

            for(int i=lower;i<=upper;i++)
            {
                tmpStr=tmpArr[0]+","+i;
                if(!hm.containsKey(tmpStr))
                    hm.put(tmpStr,1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Visited = "+hm.size());
        System.out.println("Not Visited = "+((row*column)-hm.size()));
    }

    public void dataInput()
    {
        row=20;
        column=20;
        taskList=new ArrayList<String>();
        taskList.add("1 1 5");
        taskList.add("1 1 7");
        taskList.add("1 10 12");    
        taskList.add("1 15 15"); 
        taskList.add("1 15 16"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MatrixCalculcation matrixCalculcation=new MatrixCalculcation();
        matrixCalculcation.dataInput();
        matrixCalculcation.notVisited();
    }


}
```

Comment: No, it still does not give perfect output.

Comment: @YashMehta can you please give me an example ?

Comment: According to the tasks in the code, answer should be visited = 6 and Not visited =10 but your code generates visited = 5 and not visited = 11

Comment: I think your question should have been more clearer on the first place. Please have a look at this answer, it should work i guess.

Comment: could you please accept this as answer if it serves your purpose ?

Comment: This code won't run for a big input. You are iterating from `lower` to `upper` wherein `lower` can be `1` and `upper` can be `n`(10^9). It will surely time out!!!

Comment: Yes, it gives times Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: @YashMehta User_Targaryen, Ok I didn't see that it has any time limit, it runs but take time actually. I think I can come out with a better solution... if not solved by then, then I will submit the updated post tonight

Comment: @YashMehta do you still need the solution ?

Comment: No. Thank you so much for your answer. I appreciate it!