# Gridland Metro Hackerrank Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving this problem on Hackerrank[1]: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gridland-metro

The city of Gridland is represented as a ***n by m*** matrix where the rows are numbered from 1 to ***n*** and the columns are numbered from 1 to ***m***.

Gridland has a network of train tracks that always run in straight horizontal lines along a row. In other words, the start and end points of a train track are  (**r,c1**) and (**r,c2**), where **r** represents the row number, **c1** represents the starting column, and **c2** represents the ending column of the train track.

The mayor of Gridland is surveying the city to determine the number of locations where lampposts can be placed. A lamppost can be placed in any cell that is not occupied by a train track.

Given a map of Gridland and its ***k*** train tracks, find and print the number of cells where the mayor can place lampposts.

Note: A train track may (or may not) overlap other train tracks within the same row.

**Input Format**

The first line contains three space-separated integers describing the respective values of ***n*** (the number of rows), ***m*** (the number of columns), and ***k*** (the number of train tracks). 
Each line ***i*** of the ***k***  subsequent lines contains three space-separated integers describing the respective values of ***r,c1,*** and ***c2*** that define a train track.

Print a single integer denoting the number of cells where the mayor can install lampposts.

Here's my solution:

```
import java.io. * ;
import java.util. * ;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int m = input.nextInt();
        int k = input.nextInt();
        int[][] arr = new int[n][m];
        int occupied = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(arr[i], 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            int r = input.nextInt() - 1;
            int c1 = input.nextInt() - 1;
            int c2 = input.nextInt() - 1;
            for (int j = c1; j <= c2; j++) {
                arr[r][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] != -1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out the problem in my code? (it is just passing 4 test cases on submission)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683853/count-the-cells-which-are-not-visited-in-matrix-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The constraint in the question are `1<=n,m<=10^9`.

You can't declare a two-dimensional array of this much size as it would require a huge amount of heap space, for eg if n,m are both 10^9, the size of arr would be `10^18 * 4 /( 1024 * 1024 * 1024) Gb`.

This question can be solved without using this big array. If you need any help with the correct approach i can help, but first try on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution using a HashMap, I am maintaining a map  Integer is the row number and hashset is the set of columns visited for the particular row. This map is maintained to check if there are any overlapping tracks. The code gives correct answers on the small test cases. But, in most of the test cases, it fails because of time out. Any help to optimize this code is highly appreciated.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = sc.nextInt();
        long m = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();        
        HashMap<Integer,HashSet> map = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet>(); 
        long count = n*m;
        for (int i =0;i<k;i++)
            {
            HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();    
            int row = sc.nextInt();
            int c1 = sc.nextInt();
            int c2 = sc.nextInt();
            //System.out.println(row+" "+ c1+" "+c2);
            if (map.containsKey(row))
                {
                set = map.get(row);
                for (int j = c1;j<=c2;j++)
                {
                    if(set.add(j)) count--;
                }
                //if (set.add(c2)) count--;
                map.put(row,set);
            }
                else
                {
                    for (int p = c1;p<=c2;p++)
                    {
                        if (set.add(p)) count --;
                    }
                    //if (set.add(c2)) count--;

                    map.put(row,set);
                }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend changing your algorithm based on my suggestions. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide the solution here because I don't think it's in the spirit of HackerRank. However, I have provided some hints and identified the problems with your code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();//ERROR: n ranges from 1 to 10E9, read in as a String
int m = input.nextInt();//ERROR: m ranges from 1 to 10E9, read in as String
int k = input.nextInt();
int[][] arr = new int[n][m];/*ERROR: The range of an int is 2E31-1 and large 
                                    integers will cause stack overflow anyway. 
                                    You'll need to consider a data structure 
                                    that's compatible w/ strings. Hint, consider 
                                    a hash table. */
int occupied = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(arr[i], 0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    int r = input.nextInt() - 1;//ERROR: r ranges from 1 to 10E9, read in as a String
    int c1 = input.nextInt() - 1;//ERROR: c1 ranges from 1 to 10E9, read in as a String
    int c2 = input.nextInt() - 1;//ERROR: c2 ranges from 1 to 10E9, read in as a String
    for (int j = c1; j <= c2; j++) {
        arr[r][j] = -1;
    }
}
/* NOTE: A train track may (or may not) overlap other train tracks within the 
     same row. Hence, your algorithm will need to account for track overlaps 
     and tracks that are in between of each other. For example, if a track 
     overlaps with another track in the same the row, the tracks should be 
     merged into a single track. If a smaller track is contained in a bigger 
     track, the smaller track should be ignored.*/
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] != -1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(count);
```